# if statement in process builder formula

Tags: formula, process-builder

I have a process builder formula where I need to set a date custom field based on if statement:

```
IF (
    ISPICKVAL([Account].Status, 'Active')
)
```

Then set

> [Account].Custom_Date__c + 20

Please advise how to build such formula based on if statement in process builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the IF statement should have 3 parameters, 1st- Condition, 2nd- When condition true. 3rd- When Condition false.
All three parameters separated by ,

I hope this below formula helps-

```
IF(ISPICKVAL([Account].Status, 'Active'),[Account].Custom_Date__c + 20 , [Account].Custom_Date__c)
```